# pickup and drop with space unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my character pickup and drop with the same key "space" in unity but since void update happens so fast then when I drop a monster then it instantly picks it up.

```
void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") /*( || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))*/) {

        if (map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying) {
            print("DROP space");
            map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying = false;
        }

        // pick up monster while on top of it
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i < map.monsterList.Count; i++) {
                if (map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX == map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX &&
                    map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY == map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY &&
                    map.occupationArray [map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX, map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY] == true) {
                        print("PICKUP space");
                        map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying = true;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to put pickup key as other key. I have been thinking if I add 1 second between each "space" key. So you can press space only once in one second and it could somehow fix this.

Answer (score 1):

How about using GetKeyUp instead.

GetKeyUp is called only once when you released key.

See this doc
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html

Comment: but the problem is because my Space is inside void Update, so that means this won't work. In one second it's 60 frames, which means it calls it 60 times constantly

Comment: Oh I thought u were using getkey function.
But that is weird because getkeydown and getkeyup function
called only once no matter how fast update is.

Comment: I tested with this code


void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("space down");
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("space up");
        }
    }


space down and space up log is called only once when i pressed space key

Answer (score -1):

I end up using seconds methods in my code. This means that it waits 0.25 sec before you can pick up or drop again. Now this prevents it to loop all the time. If someone else has better solution then please provide it. For now I am using this.

```
void Update() {
    // there is 0.25 second between that player can PickUp again or Drop again

    if (!map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying) {
        timeLeftToPressAgain -= Time.deltaTime;
        timeLeftToPressAgain = Mathf.Max(timeLeftToPressAgain, -0.25f);
    }
    else {
        timeLeftToPressAgain += Time.deltaTime;
        timeLeftToPressAgain = Mathf.Min(timeLeftToPressAgain, 0.25f);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") /*( || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))*/) {
        // while carrying the time builds up for player to Drop and vice versa in PickUp
        if (map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying && timeLeftToPressAgain > 0) {

            map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying = false;

            timeLeftToPressAgain = 0.25f;
        }

        // pick up monster while on top of it
        else if (!map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying && timeLeftToPressAgain < 0) {
            for(int i = 0; i < map.monsterList.Count; i++) {
                if (map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX == map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX &&
                    map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY == map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY &&
                    map.occupationArray [map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX, map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY] == true) {

                        map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying = true;
                        timeLeftToPressAgain = -0.25f;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to complete it: You could have done something like this:

```
bool pressedSpace = false;
    void Update() {
        pressedSpace = true; // Only called once
        if (!pressedSpace && Input.GetKeyDown("space") /*( || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))*/) {

            if (map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying) {
                print("DROP space");
                map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying = false;
            }
            // pick up monster while on top of it
            else {
                for(int i = 0; i < map.monsterList.Count; i++) {
                    if (map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX == map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileX &&
                        map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY == map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().tileY &&
                        map.occupationArray [map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileX, map.monsterList[i].GetComponent<Monsters>().tileY] == true) {
                            print("PICKUP space");
                            map.selectedUnit.GetComponent<Unit>().carrying = true;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then after a little wait you can reset pressedSpace to false.

Comment: what do you mean by "And then after a little wait you can reset pressedSpace to false." because I want it quite quickly. In your code there is no pressedSpace = true; which means it never goes back.